# JSF submit button after submit call javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I have a form in my jsf page(a popup) that I used to upload a file. I need to refresh the parent page when the file is uploaded. What is the best approach that I can use to achive this task.

My JSF page is simple and looks like this

```xml
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul class="page">
        <li>
            <h:messages layout="list" for="uploadForm" styleClass="generic-message"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:outputLabel for="file" value="select a file" />
            <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{aBean.file}" required="true" requiredMessage="File need to be selected"/>
            <h:message for="file" styleClass="msg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:outputLabel value="Name" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{aBean.name}" label="#{aBean.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is required"/>
            <h:message for="name" styleClass="msg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{aBean.submit}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the popup, you need to conditionally render a

```xml
<script>window.opener.location.reload(true);</script>
```

so that the parent window will be refreshed.

You can do this by triggering some boolean in the action method

```
private boolean reloadParent;

public void submit() {
    // ...
    reloadParent = true;
}

public boolean isReloadParent() {
    return reloadParent;
}
```

and wrapping the script in an `<ui:fragment>` with a `rendered` attribute

```xml
<ui:fragment rendered="#{aBean.reloadParent}">
    <script>window.opener.location.reload(true);</script>
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: thanx balusc for the prompt reply..
I added my JSF code
<code>
      <ui:fragment rendered="#{aBean.print}">
                <script type="text/javascript" >
                    window.print();
                </script>
            </ui:fragment>
</code>
I put this code block just under
<code>
<ui:composition template="/templates/aLayout.xhtml">
</code>
but the javascript function doesn't get triggered 
is there any thing wrong where I have placed my <ui:fragment>

Comment: It needs to be placed in the popup page.

Comment: I have <ui:define name="sub-heading"> areas in my popup page and I have put the UI fragment section outside all these UI defined araes..so the javascript is not getting triggered.
really sorry if I sounds confusing..just little new to JSF..

Comment: Put it inside the `<ui:define>`.

Comment: I have added the VIewScope for my bean and I have a postConstruct method in my bean as well.
WHen I click submit, I see my boolean value "reloadParent" getting the value "true"
but thereafter it goes again to the post construct method, so my boolean value remains to be false.. please advise me on this issue

Comment: was able to resolve it balusc..thanx a million...I will be reading more abt JSF..